# C# - Avoid reading csv file everytime

Tags: c#, csv, nosql

My input file have 7 million rows.
It is taking long time to read the file. After that I have to modify the data based on clients requirement. If client add a new requirement then I have to read the csv file again.
Is there any way to read and store csv file in some format in c#. So I can avoid reading csv file everytime.
I cannot use SQL ,SQLITE or any other database to store the data.

Comment: CSV Files are effectively a `List<List<string>>`. Parse them as such and keep them in memory?

Comment: It is interesting you have a policy to not use a DB when working with 7 million rows of data.  It also depends on the frequency of these requirements if storing all that data into memory.  You could create an index file and use that to load only the data that needs to be changed.  This is bordering design and technique versus a coding issue.

Comment: Also, the vast majority of the time taken to parse a 7 million row CSV file will be Disk I/O. Have you tried compressing it, and decompressing it into memory when you need to make changes?

Comment: How come you can't use SQLITE (for example)? It sounds like a perfect fit otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

1. Use another form of database - e.g. SQL, Mongo DB, Raven DB, Lucene
2. Store the file in memory, and only save the changes at a certain
   time
3. Break the file into smaller files, e.g ID's 0-100000, 100001-200000, etc
4. Maintain another file of the 'changes' and recombine them as needed (this is probably a bad idea)